# How to create the effect of having a separate view controller on the left and another on the right side of the landscape mode on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I want to create the same effect as in the imdb app (landscape). They have a static view on the left and another one on the right side that creates the impression of having a navigation controller that only starts from the midle of the view. You have to see the app imdb to understand.

Comment: The same as in the settings view on iPad.

Comment: UISplitViewController was the solution.